# VBA sum row base on different two condition and delete row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to create a macro that will sum the unit column base by Product & DC. It will populate out the same product name, code with dc code and code without.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

For i = 2 to lstrow

Next I

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

| Product | DC | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 | 2 |
| ABC | 1234 | 4 |
| ABC | 1234 | 4 |
| DEF | 5678 | 2 |
| DEF | 5678 | 2 |
| GHI | 9012 | 2 |

I want to the output as below:-

| Product | Unit with DC Code | Unit Without DC Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 6 | 2 |
| DEF | 4 | 0 |
| GHI | 2 | 0 |

Comment: I count 8 ABC units with DC code. Is your result table incorrect? Also: why not simply a SUMIFS function instead of a VBA code? If you are not looking for a formula, why tag the question with `excel-formula`?

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table?

Comment: Based on what logic "Unit with DC Code" summarized 6? 3 occurrences in "DC" column multiplied by 2 in first "Unit" occurrence? "sum the unit column base by Product & DC" is not clear enough to make a processing algorithm, I think...

Comment: I need do write it in VBA so didnt consider pivot table.

Comment: Yes. I raise another questions... in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438024/vba-sum-row-base-on-different-two-condition-and-delete-row   Not sure why by using your method is not working if got column in front of the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sum Unique

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- If you want to overwrite ('mimic' `RemoveDuplicates`), then just replace `Sheet2` with `Sheet1` and uncomment the `Delete below` section. Keep in mind that you won't be able to undo.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sumUnique()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Data As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        LastRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Data = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 3)
    End With
    
    ' Write unique values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim arr(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim cArr As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                dict.Add Key, arr
            End If
            If Data(r, 2) = 0 Then
                cArr = dict(Key)
                cArr(2) = cArr(2) + Data(r, 3)
                dict(Key) = cArr
            Else
                cArr = dict(Key)
                cArr(1) = cArr(1) + Data(r, 3)
                dict(Key) = cArr
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write values from Unique Dictionary to Result Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dict.Count + 1
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rCount, 1 To 3)
    Result(1, 1) = "Product"
    Result(1, 2) = "Unit With DC Code"
    Result(1, 3) = "Unit Without DC Code"
    If rCount > 1 Then
        r = 1
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            r = r + 1
            Result(r, 1) = Key
            Result(r, 2) = CLng(dict(Key)(1))
            Result(r, 3) = CLng(dict(Key)(2))
        Next Key
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 3)
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Result
        ' Delete below.
        '.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I try to add more columns with the some condition and modify base on your coding but fail to get what i want... Could you guide me? I already added the questions...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of VBA code that should do the trick:

```
Sub SubWhyNotSUMIFS()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim StrPreviousProduct As String
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngResult = Range("D1")
    Set RngSource = Range("A2:C2")
    Set RngSource = Range(RngSource, RngSource.End(xlDown))
    
    'Creating space for the result.
    RngResult.EntireColumn.Insert
    RngResult.EntireColumn.Insert
    RngResult.EntireColumn.Insert
    
    'Reporting the headers of the result list.
    Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(0, -3)
    RngResult.Value = "Product"
    RngResult.Offset(0, 1) = "Unit with DC Code"
    RngResult.Offset(0, 2) = "Unit Without DC Code"
    
    'Covering each cell of the first column of RngSource.
    For Each RngTarget In RngSource.Columns(1).Cells
        
        'Checking if it's a different product.
        If StrPreviousProduct <> RngTarget.Value Then
            
            'Setting RngResult for a new row.
            Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(1, 0)
            
            'Changing StrPreviousProduct.
            StrPreviousProduct = RngTarget.Value
            
            'Reporting the results.
            RngResult.Value = RngTarget.Value
            RngResult.Offset(0, 1).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RngSource.Columns(3), RngSource.Columns(1), RngTarget.Value, RngSource.Columns(2), "<>0")
            RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RngSource.Columns(3), RngSource.Columns(1), RngTarget.Value, RngSource.Columns(2), 0)
            
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

You can reverse-engineer it. The lines you will be most interested into are:

```
RngResult.Offset(0, 1).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RngSource.Columns(3), RngSource.Columns(1), RngTarget.Value, RngSource.Columns(2), "<>0")
RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RngSource.Columns(3), RngSource.Columns(1), RngTarget.Value, RngSource.Columns(2), 0)
```

Translated in actual formulas they are basically this:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,D2,B2:B7,"<>0")
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,D2,B2:B7,"=0")
```

Assuming that your list spans from cell A1 (headers) to cell C7, that in cell D2 there is the unique product you are looking for. The code itself dynamically covers the list. Since it looks like your list is the only thing in their own columns, formulas like these:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D2,B:B,"<>0")
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D2,B:B,"=0")
```

should still be effective.